# I have a richtextbox in C# but when I clicked toggle button underline stay clicked all the thime

Tags: c#, xaml, richtextbox

this is the code in xaml about richtextbox:
The toolbar is the next, and every buttons that I added:

The view of designer placed in the next link:

I need, when I clicked de bold button, underline, italic, bullets, numbering, align (left, right, center, justify) the part of text I selected change to bold format (for example) and then, when I click enter and I write a new line, the button bold not stay clicked.

Apologize for my english.

Thanks for all!

Comment: There is no code provided here. Please provide us the code you wrote.

Comment: Where I write my code?

Comment: Just edit you question and paste some code you wrote or give us github link.